# How does git branch for 4 different environment

Tags: git, github

Currently, we have four different IT environments, dev for the developer, and test for the tester to test the code.  UAT is a production like environment, which is for some end-user to use the product before going to production. Production is production.

So I have read some article online about Git source control, but it looks like git only has development branch (for developer) and master branch(for production), feature branch for adding a feature, the release branch is for the tester to test it.

Therefore, I was wondering if it is necessary to have a separate UAT and test branch? So the end-user and tester can test the code separately. If so how can I set up those two branch in git ?

Answer (score 6):

Git branches are completely separate to the concept of multiple code environments, and don't have to map out one-to-one. Git itself should be restricted to `develop`, `feature`, `bugfix`, `hotfix`, `release` and `master`. This is illustrated in [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow):

[image: Git Flow]

Typically `develop` is deployed to the development environment, `release` is deployed to the test environment and `master` is deployed to the production environment. However, note that this is not a *required* deployment strategy. If you have additional environments such as UAT, you ultimately simply want to test what the *end-user* will see. The code in the latest `release` should be identical to that of `master`, so it shouldn't matter which of these two you deploy to the UAT environment; it comes down to personal preference. Personally, I would opt for `release`, due to `master` typically being considered the "last known good point". Your end-users may find some bugs that your own testers may not!

Having said this, it's also worth noting that there is a current push to ["shift left" in the DevOps circles](https://devops.com/devops-shift-left-avoid-failure/), where the entire testing cycle takes place on the `feature` branch itself, with `develop` being considered "shippable code". In this scenario, `develop` could make its way right through to production, so (in theory), *all* environments would point against develop. However, I would still recommend following Git Flow personally.

Comment: Git Flow is _a_ Git workflow. Depending on your environment you may very well use a different git branching strategy.

Answer (score 3):

Git doesn't care how many branches you make or what you use them for. Master is just the default branch name; there is nothing special about it.

To setup however many branches you want in git:

```
// get everything of a working version into git
git add some_file.txt
git commit -m "initial commit"

git branch release
git branch testing
git branch UAT
git branch whatever_name_you_want
```

Then all the branches will be on the same version. Your changes after this point will only affect one branch. To bring them to your other branches, checkout and merge. (And remember to checkout back to your first branch if you don't want to make additional changes to release/testing branches).

```
git checkout release
// I usually use master as the main dev branch but the name doesn't matter
git merge master


// remember to checkout back if you want to keep writing changes to your dev branch
git checkout master
```

The same steps should apply to any GUI based git software.

Answer (score 1):

*You can have different branches based on your branching stretegy:*

You can have `UAT branch` (containing code undergoing UAT testing) & `develop branch` (containing current unit tested code) & master branch (Containing code in Production). You can also have `hotfix branch` (for working on Production hot fixes, forked from master branch). It all depends on your branching strategy. As @Obsidian Age mentioned, git flow workflow is standard branching strategy being followed.

*If you want to work on multiple branches at same time:*

You can work on multiple branches of same remote repository using different local folders for each branch, using [git worktree feature](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree). Earlier, you can only have one local reference to remote repository and pointing to single branch. Now, with git worktree, you can work on multiple branches, based on your need.